# fitting accuracy

Tags: fitting

I tried to fit my data (see bellow)  with the following code. It works but I get the following message :

> NonlinearModelFit::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

I changed the number of iteration from 100 to 200 or more using `MaxIterations` but style have the problem. So I am not sure about the accurancy of my fit...even if it works.

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/ADajyTYF", "TSV"]

(* data = ReadList[file, Number, RecordLists -> True]; *)
dataT = Transpose[data];
dataT = {10*dataT[[1]], dataT[[2]]};
error = Transpose[data][[3]];
data = Transpose[dataT];
nmax = Length[data];

mu0 := 4*Pi*10^(-7);
Ms := 3.41;                                                           \

DD:=    2*10^(-3)          \
lM = 10^9*Sqrt[2*A*mu0/Ms^2]
lD[DD_] := 10^9*2*DD*mu0/Ms^2
lD[0.003]
h2[Hp_, q_, RH_] := Hp^2/(1 + q^2*RH^2)^2
Heff[q_, H_, A_] := H + 2*A/(Ms/mu0)*q^2*10^(18)               
p[q_, H_, A_] := Ms/Heff[q, H, A]                                                                 \

nenner[q_, H_, DD_, A_] := 1 - p[q, H, A]^2*lD[DD]^2*q^2
chi[Hp_, q_, H_, DD_, RH_, A_] := (4*p[q, H, A]^3*h2[Hp, q, RH]*lD[DD]*q)/nenner[q, H, DD, A]^2 

singlefit2 = 
  NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   chi[Hp, q, 5, DD, RH, 
    A], {{Hp, 2000}, {DD, 0.001}, {RH, 15}, {A, 10*10^(-12)}}, q,
       Weights -> error, MaxIterations -> 100];

singlefit2["BestFitParameters"];
singlefit2["EstimatedVariance"];
singlefit2["ParameterErrors"];
singlefit2["ParameterConfidenceIntervals"];
MatrixForm[singlefit2["CorrelationMatrix"]];
Print[singlefit2["ParameterTable"]];
```

Comment: I can't access your dataset from the link you provided

Comment: It should be fine now.

Comment: What are `Ms`,  `mu0`, `h2`, and `lD`?

Comment: They are constant parameters.

Comment: I changed your link to your data to a permanent repository easy to `Import` from.  You should include any clarification in your question (please [edit]). Also give typical values for your constant parameters, we can't reproduce your problem without that. If you expect to inspire anybody to **volunteer their time to look at your problem**, then you should help us as much as possible.

Comment: I get that `Ms` and `mu0` can be constants.  But `h2` and `lD` appear to be functions.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I edited the code and add the missing parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer, but some hints.

1. You set `DD := 2*10^(-3)`, but in `NonlinearModelFit` you want to use it as a parameter.
2. You define `lM = 10^9*Sqrt[2*A*mu0/Ms^2]` , but never use it.
3. The starting parameter seem to be not good. Try to find better one with

   `Manipulate[
     LogPlot[chi[Hp, q, 5, DD, RH, A], {q, 0, 1.2}, PlotRange -> All, 
      Epilog -> Point[data]], {{Hp, 2000}, 0, 2000}, {{DD, 10^-3}, 10^-4, 10^-1}, {{RH, 15}, 0, 30}, {{A, 10^-11}, 10^-16, 10^-10}]`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comments and will try to do that ;)

Comment: Using manipulate, I can find good approximations parameters but when I put as initial parameters in code as initial parameters, then I get the following message : `NonlinearModelFit::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the gradient is larger than the tolerance specified by the AccuracyGoal option. There is a possibility that the method has stalled at a point that is not a local minimum.`